# Reproducing a table lock error in Advantage Table

Tags: delphi, datatable, advantage-database-server

I am running two instances of a program and they are both accessing a TAds table.

I want to reproduce a table lock for testing, but am having trouble.

I made a button that when clicked runs the code -

SomeTAdsTable.Edit;

When I click on the button on both instances of the program I am not getting any Advantage Table errors.

I am assuming it would be trying to edit the same record on both instances of the program.

Can anyone help me reproduce a table lock error with advantage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the TAdsTable instances reference the same table, are are both positioned to the same [record number](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/ade_recno_7.htm?zoom_highlightsub=tadstable.recno) and the [record locking mode](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/ade_adsrecordlockingmode.htm?zoom_highlightsub=lmPessimistic) is set to `lmPessimistic`, then the second edit should result in a lock error.

However, the [LockTable](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/ade_locktable.htm?zoom_highlightsub=tadstable.locktable) method might be applicable in this situation.